# inside a $.each loop, getting two different kind of objects returns value and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, local-storage

I have a localStorage which creates keys dynamically. They basically store `'name'` and `'age'`, with different prefix for each case. To differentiate I'm using `endsWith()` method.

I have a function which will use both data to `.append` that to an element. The issue is that at the moment function is called, I can't get it working given undefined as result:

```
// below I'm faking result of localStorage
var fakeStorage = {
  'aaa-name': 'John',
  'aaa-age': 20,
  'bbb-name': 'Robert',
  'bbb-age': 45,
  'ccc-name': 'James',
  'bbb-age': 30,
  'somethingUneeded': 'cars',
  'anotherSomethingUneeded': 'money'
}

$.each(fakeStorage, function (key, value) {
  if (!key.endsWith('name') && !key.endsWith('age')) {
      return
  }
  var name
  var age
  if (key.endsWith('name')) {
    name = value
  } else {
    // get results of "age"
    age = value
  }
  console.log(name)
  // returns: 
  // John
  // undefined
  // Robert
  // undefined
  // James
  // undefined

  console.log(age)
  // returns: 
  // 20
  // undefined
  // 45
  // undefined
  // 30
  // undefined

  // Here's the function I need for the sake of undertanding.
  // with the above output I can't call it due to undefined
  // functionToAppendBoth(name, age)
})
```

How can I work on that code so I can skip "undefined" values? I did a CodePen with current result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLRjNg?editors=1010

Comment: You have an if condition, so either name or age is assigned, therefore one of then will be undefined.

Comment: sure, makes sense. but can't think a way without using if statement to do what I'm trying

Comment: Store your data as array of objects.. That data structure you have is not efficient or practical

Comment: @charlietfl I'm collecting from localStorage. I tried using Object.keys() but then I lost the value (key turned to index and value is now the storage id). Any advice on how to improve that?

Comment: store an array of objects that  in localStorage using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(). Or one  main object that  contains the array among other properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a new Object and assign it the values that can be easily used later,

I can think of structure like:

```
{
  name: [],
  age: []
}
```

Example Snippet:

```js
// below I'm faking result of localStorage
var fakeStorage = {
  'aaa-name': 'John',
  'aaa-age': 20,
  'bbb-name': 'Robert',
  'bbb-age': 45,
  'ccc-name': 'James',
  'bbb-age': 30,
  'somethingUneeded': 'cars',
  'anotherSomethingUneeded': 'money'
}
var tempObj = {
  name: [],
  age: []
};
$.each(fakeStorage, function(key, value) {
  if (!key.endsWith('name') && !key.endsWith('age')) {
    return
  }
  if (key.endsWith('name')) {
    tempObj.name.push(value)
  } else {
    tempObj.age.push(value)
  }
});
console.log(tempObj);

$.each(tempObj.name, function(index) {
  console.log(tempObj.name[index] + ' ' + tempObj.age[index]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or we can keep an condition check to see if we have both name and age.

Example Snippet:

```js
// below I'm faking result of localStorage
var fakeStorage = {
  'aaa-name': 'John',
  'aaa-age': 20,
  'bbb-name': 'Robert',
  'bbb-age': 45,
  'ccc-name': 'James',
  'bbb-age': 30,
  'somethingUneeded': 'cars',
  'anotherSomethingUneeded': 'money'
}
var tempObj = {
  name: '',
  age: ''
};
$.each(fakeStorage, function(key, value) {
  if (!key.endsWith('name') && !key.endsWith('age')) {
    return
  }
  if (key.endsWith('name')) {
    tempObj.name = value
  } else {
    tempObj.age = value
  }
  if (tempObj.name && tempObj.age) {
    console.log(tempObj.name + ' ' + tempObj.age);
    //call desired function here;
    tempObj = {
      name: '',
      age: ''
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```